# How to use nimbus oauth oidc sdk to get token using a proxy

Tags: java, oauth, proxy, openid-connect, nimbus

I tried the oauth token request with client credentials as described here: https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-oauth-openid-connect-sdk/examples/oauth/token-request#client-credentials

It works perfectly fine on my local machine but in the productive environment all calls to the outside world must use a proxy. Is there any way to use the nimbus sdk with a configurable proxy? I havent found any possibility to set a proxy while creating the token request or sending it.

Answer (score 0):

The support chat helped me.
Version 8.2 adds proxy support. I still used 8.3 and just had to update the used version of the sdk.

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.nimbusds/oauth2-oidc-sdk/latest/com/nimbusds/oauth2/sdk/http/HTTPRequest.html